# Find/list the Unused storage accounts in azure using powershell

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-powershell, azure-automation

Trying to get the list of **unused/inactive storage accounts** in azure using powershell. Below is my script which im trying it will provide the storage account name and last modified date of your Azure storage accounts, but i need to list only the unused storage accounts names not all the storage accounts, for that some condition/filter i need to provide to achieve the same. Please assist me to solve this. Thanks in Advance

It will output the results into a table detailing the name and last modified date of your Azure storage accounts.

```
& {
foreach ($storageAccount in Get-AzStorageAccount) {
$storageAccountName = $storageAccount.StorageAccountName
$resourceGroupName = $storageAccount.ResourceGroupName


  # Get storage account key
     $storageAccountKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -Name $storageAccountName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName).Value[0]
    
     # Create storage account context using above key
     $context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey
    
     # Get the last modified date
     $lastModified = Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $context | Sort-Object -Property @{Expression = {$_.LastModified.DateTime}} | Select-Object -Last 1 -ExpandProperty LastModified

             # Collect the information to output to a table when the for loop has completed
             New-Object psobject -Property @{
                 Name = $storageAccountName;
                 LastModified = $lastModified.DateTime;
                 ResourceGroupName = $resourceGroupName
             }

 }
} | Format-Table Name, LastModified, ResourceGroupName -autosize
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]Use `get-date`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date

and use the `Where-Object`.

```
     # ADD THIS
 $lastModDate = (get-date).AddDays(-5).Date
 $lastMod = $lastModified | Where-Object { ($_.DateTime).Date -lt $lastModDate}
 
 # If $lastMod.DateTime is NOT empty, then:
 if ($lastMod.DateTime) { 
 
    # Write-Host "variable is NOT null " + $storageAccountName # For testing purpose
    # Collect the information to output to a table when the for loop has completed
    New-Object psobject -Property @{
        Name = $storageAccountName;
        LastModified = $lastMod.DateTime; # CHANGE THIS
        ResourceGroupName = $resourceGroupName
    }
 }
```

https://www.techielass.com/find-unused-storage-accounts-in-azure/

With your script:
[image]

With my changes:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Niclas -im getting error ** $lastModified = Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $context | Sort- … This request is not authorized to perform this operation** attached screenshot for reference.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstoragecontainer?view=azps-9.3.0#-context - it is running your original script, nothing changed. Do your original script execute without errors?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same result as below:***

By using the same script, I got the storage account name and last modified date of the Azure storage accounts.

[image]

To get only the **unused/inactive storage accounts** in azure using PowerShell, I modified the script like below:

I agree with @*Niclas*, you need make use of **`get-date`** command.

```
& {
  foreach ($storageAccount in Get-AzStorageAccount) {
    $storageAccountName = $storageAccount.StorageAccountName
    $resourceGroupName = $storageAccount.ResourceGroupName
    $storageAccountKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -Name $storageAccountName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName).Value[0]
    $context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey
    $lastModified = Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $context | Sort-Object -Property @{Expression = {$_.LastModified.DateTime}} | Select-Object -Last 1 -ExpandProperty LastModified
    $unusedacc = (Get-Date).AddDays(-10)
    if ($lastModified.DateTime -lt $unusedacc) {
        New-Object psobject -Property @{
        Name = $storageAccountName;
        LastModified = $lastModified.DateTime;
        ResourceGroupName = $resourceGroupName
      }
    }
  }
} | Format-Table Name, LastModified, ResourceGroupName -autosize
```

[image]

> **Note**: Based on your requirement you can change the number of days in this line `$unusedacc = (Get-Date).AddDays(-10)`.

If there are no unused Storage accounts, then it will return blank results like below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response @Rukmini -getting error ** $lastModified = Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $context | Sort- … This request is not authorized to perform this operation** attached screenshot for reference, what permission it requires to perform that?

Comment: Could you include the roles assigned to your account?

Comment: Try assigning `Storage Blob Data Reader` to your user account and check..

Comment: -yes i have assigned both **Storage Blob Data Reader and Owner** role facing same issue.

Comment: I tried the same in my environment and it worked for me without any issue

Comment: Thanks @Rukmini - i have figured out the issue. Is there is a possible way to get the Location of those storage accounts?

Comment: @DSH can you elaborate on what the issue was?  I'm having this exact same issue.